# Reduce page margin of a Bootstrap template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm customising a Bootstrap template and I can't figure out how to reduce the width of the page margin (so the text is closer to the edge of the page).

For example, if you look at the image below, the text is quite a long way way from the edge of the page. I would like it so the "we will get back to you as soon as possible!" part would continue on the same line, and not start a new line.

https://gyazo.com/e75d1decdd4070446fc73cf95dafd381

In the bootstrap.css file there is the following code which I thought would change it, but it did not work.

```
.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

I'm sure it's something really simple but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post a demo of the current code. Screenshot will not help us find a solution.

Comment: What part of the code should I post? I am unsure what part of the code would change this. The template I am using is this one: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/ which has a link to the download of all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template that you are using, `max-width` is set to `1000px`. Change it to `100%` or remove it. The text is currently centered. Align it to the left as well.

```
header .header-content .header-content-inner {
  max-width: 100%;
}

header .header-content {
  text-align: left;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this. This reduced the margin of the text at the top of the page, but not the text in the "Let's get in touch section". Would you know what part would change that?

Comment: Where do you want that text to be? It is centered and does not have any margin. Updated the code BTW.

Comment: When I make it uncentered the text still starts near the middle of the page, as there is some sort of margin or padding to the left of it. If you look at these two images it should show you what I mean. https://gyazo.com/44f91e8155649dd69da5cfeee38fae4b and https://gyazo.com/cb703e98fee7583f0db31019cecce273 Is it possible to get the text to start further to the left, by removing the padding or the margin? Thanks!

Comment: I tried the updated code and that aligns the header section to the left. The text in the images on Gyazo are not part of the header section and so any changes made to that code does not change that part of the text. The text in the images are part of the "row" and "container" class, but any changes I make to that do not work. I really appreciate you trying to help :)

Comment: You will need to setup a demo page that you are working on so I can improve my help with exact solution :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for all your help, I managed to figure it out in the end! Have a great day

Comment: Welcome. Have a great day! :)